# Replacing part of a matched regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse some very badly delimited files and ultimately change them to a CSV. I'm looking to match on number, whitespace, and then letter, and replace the whitespace with a comma.

For example If I had the line '08:34:45 home' I'd like it to recognize the '5 h' and make it '08:34:45,home'. I understand why what I have below isn't working correctly, but can someone explain how to tell Powershell that I want to keep the \d and the \D?

```
Get-Content -path C:\file.txt |

ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "(\d\s\D)",','}
```

Comment: Figured it out:

ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "(\d)\s(\D)",'$1,$2'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you put in parentheses `( )` is captured by the regular expression, and you can access it with $1 for the first set, $2 for the second set, etc.

so you could try two capture groups:

`$_ -replace '(\d)\s(\D)', '$1,$2'`

See also: http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Example_-_Replace_With_Captures for more details.